# caching images in iis6

Tags: iis-6, cache, http-headers

i try to make the images in my website read from the cache
i try adding http heading like [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/yevgenif/image111_3809BD39.png)

but i still get in Yshow that it isn't caching.
how can i check if a specific image has expire header?

Comment: My guess is the problem might be that the website needs to set the correct caching headers for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a network sniffer like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or a browser plug in like [iehttpheaders](http://www.blunck.se/iehttpheaders/iehttpheaders.html) (MSIE), [liveheaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) or [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) (Firefox)